# Affine maps problems

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

How to find out a particular affine map when some points are given, say if it takes (0,0) to (1,1), (1,0) to (3,2) and (0,1) to (2,4)?

Answer (score 3):

I am agree with @Fredrik that $$T(\vec x)=A\vec{x}+\vec{b}$$ and $b=(1,1)$. For determined $A$ we have :

$$T(\vec x)-\vec{b}=A\vec{x}$$

Now you can consider $A$ as linear transformation and so $A$ makes $(1,0) \to (2,1)$, and makes $(0,1) \to (1,3)$ and then we have:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}2&1\\1&3 \end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore:

$$T(\vec x)=\begin{pmatrix}2&1\\1&3 \end{pmatrix}\vec{x}+(1,1)$$

Answer (score 2):

A affine map $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ looks like $T(\vec x)=A\vec{x}+\vec{b}$ for some $2 \times 2$-matrix $A$.

The first condition, that $(0,0) \mapsto (1,1)$ immediately shows that $\vec{b}=(1,1)$.

Now, define a new map $R$ by $R(\vec{x})=T(\vec{x})-(1,1)$. Then $R$ is a linear map, so that it is completely described by its matrix. Can you do it from here?